# How can I start node server on Hybris Commerce Server start

Tags: node.js, sap-commerce-cloud

SAP Commerce 1905

I have one node application which i want to integrate with my Hybris. I have created one custom addon and put my node application files inside addon extension. Now i want to run the below command on Hybris server start.

```
nohup npm start > output.log&
```

I am able to start my node server on ant build by putting npm command under **myextension_compileuisrc_executor** buildcallback.

But my goal is to perform only npm install on **myextension_compileuisrc_executor** not node server start.

Thats why i am looking over the way of starting node.js server on Hybris Server Start. I could not find any target in buildcallback where i can inject my server start command.

How to achieve that ?

**UPDATE :**

Tried with **myextension_before_startHybrisServer** as well but no luck -

```
<macrodef name="myextension_before_startHybrisServer">

    <sequential>

        <npm-start/>

    </sequential>

</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I tried to write the normal macro

```
    <sequential>
        <echo message="JJJJJJ RAUSHAN JAAAA" />

    </sequential>

</macrodef>

output:
 [echo] JJJJJJ RAUSHAN JAAAA
     [echo] Checking lock flag for the platform
     [exec] --> Wrapper Started as Console
     [exec] Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.29
```

Command: >ant startHybrisServer

Comment: Correct, on ant startHybrisServer, its working. I noticed when starting server using `. ./hybrisserver.sh` then this command task is not calling, may be thats why macro is not calling. Do you have any idea how we can call the macro when starting server using `. ./hybrisserver.sh` ?

Comment: I think this buildcallback works on ant command only. Do you have any idea how Solr server is starting on hybris server start ? May be they have created custom task runner

Comment: Hi, This is happening when hybris loads all the spring bean in the application context.

<alias name="defaultSolrServerService" alias="solrServerService" />
 <bean id="defaultSolrServerService" class="de.hybris.platform.solrserver.impl.DefaultSolrServerService"
  init-method="startServers" destroy-method="stopServers">
  <property name="solrServerControllerFactory" ref="solrServerControllerFactory" />
 </bean>
-->during bean load it calls init-method

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try to write custom micro in build-callbacks.

```
<macrodef name="xxxstorefront_getnpm">
 <sequential>


        <echo message="Checking for NPM" />

        <if>
            <os family="windows" />
            <then>
                <exec dir="${platformhome}" executable="cmd.exe" osfamily="windows">
                    <arg line="/c" />
                    <arg line="npm.bat" />
                </exec>
            </then>
            <else>
                <exec dir="${platformhome}" executable="sh" osfamily="unix">
                    <arg line="-c ./npm.sh" />
                </exec>
            </else>
        </if>


    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Then add reference of this callback like this.

```
<macrodef name="xxxstorefront_compileuisrc_executor">
    <sequential>
        <xxxstorefront_getnpm/>

    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Hi @Raushan, compileuisrc_executor is being called when building the code. I am looking for a way to start node at at the time of server start.

Answer (score 0):

there there is a workaround that you can try.

Please make a folder like this \hybris\config\customize\platform\resourcesant/platformadministration.xml

and copy existing platformadministration.xml and create own micro definitions:

```
<macrodef name="xxxstorefront_getnpm">
```

```
    <echo message="Checking for NPM" />

    <if>
        <os family="windows" />
        <then>
            <exec dir="${platformhome}" executable="cmd.exe" osfamily="windows">
                <arg line="/c" />
                <arg line="npm.bat" />
            </exec>
        </then>
        <else>
            <exec dir="${platformhome}" executable="sh" osfamily="unix">
                <arg line="-c ./npm.sh" />
            </exec>
        </else>
    </if>


</sequential>
```

then create file \hybris\config\customize\platform\build.xml

and add newly created micro definition in build.xml just above this.

```
 <target name="startHybrisServer" description="Starts the hybris Server">
    <callback extname="" target="before_startHybrisServer"/>
    <--**CUSTOM MICRO DEF**>
    <startHybrisServer/>
    <callback extname="" target="after_startHybrisServer"/>
</target>
```

Then save file and run >> ant customize.

> > ant clean all && hybrisserver.bat

Comment: Yes this can work, but this is not a right way to do. I am wondering why before_startHybrisServer is not working in my extension buildcallback even though callback defined in platform build.xml

Comment: Hi I tried to write the normal macro 
<macrodef name="xxxx_before_startHybrisServer">

     <sequential>
   <echo message="JJJJJJ RAUSHAN JAAAA" />

     </sequential>

 </macrodef>

output:
 [echo] JJJJJJ RAUSHAN JAAAA
     [echo] Checking lock flag for the platform
     [exec] --> Wrapper Started as Console
     [exec] Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.29
     
Command: >ant startHybrisServer